# This update does not come from a source that supports changelogs

Tags: ppa, launchpad

When I get an update via update-manager for a software like blender/vlc, I like to see what has been fixed/changed. But the software updater doesn't show me the changes from a ppa added software.

I added the ppa for blender/vlc (this only applies to the software I added a ppa for)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cheleb/blender-svn
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install blender
```

And vlc like this.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

And when i run update-manager, or update manager pop-ups 
I see that vlc/blender have updates but, I can't see what has been changed/fixed

this is the message I get, the screenshot below is for mupen but it's the same thing.
(I updated vlc and blender, didn't wanna wait for the next update)

[image: update-manager-ppa-update-error?]

```
This update does not come from a source that supports changelogs.
```

(by the way I have a dutch Ubuntu, so the above text i Google translated it!)
It only shows which version you have and to which version you be upgrading to.

So my question is, how do I get the change-log tab of update-manager working. If it's even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PPA does not seem to support changelogs, there is even a bug reported in Launchpad about it:

[Bug #253119 “PPA packages do not show a changelog in update-mana...” : Bugs : Launchpad itself](https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+bug/253119)

Comment: Thanks. I posted a comment on the bug report, but i don't think it will be fixed for the release of 12.10. Since it's a bug report from 2008 ;(

Comment: Ya, also it is set at low priority.

Comment: Go mark yourself as affected, and hopefully that will increase its priority.

Answer (score 0):

As saji89 mentioned in their answer, the bug is logged here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+bug/253119

And if you scroll down you can see that as of 2016, a fix was introduced that works only if you have python3-launchpadlib installed on your system. So I ran `apt install python3-launchpadlib` and the changelogs seem to be showing up for me now.